# PlayFramework how to access list from super controller

Tags: java, controller, superclass

I am completing my university project, but I encountered weird problem. Since I am a student, apologize in the adavance if it is prosaic.
I have my BasicCommonController which has List backendErrors = new ArrayList<>() 
, and I have another Controller which extends BasicCommonController, and I'm able to access backendErrors list from BasicCommonController, but I am not able
to put new Element to the list, wchich is always empty. I have tried to access via super.backendErrors, but it also does not work.
How to add some error to the super.backendErrors and access it in another Controllers

Comment: please add some code !

Answer (score 0):

this is abstract controller:

```
package controllers;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import play.Logger;
import play.Play;
import play.mvc.Controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by vv on 22.04.2017.
 */
public class BasicAbstractController extends Controller {

    public static final String GO_HOME = "/";

    public List<String> backendErrors = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String getPlaceToObserve(){
        String place = Play.application().configuration().getString("storage.place");
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(place)){
            return place;
        }
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }

    public static String getServerInstance(){
        String instance = Play.application().configuration().getString("storage.place");
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(instance)){
            return instance;
        }
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

this is example controller

```
package controllers;

import com.google.common.io.Files;
import com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.RE;
import constans.AppCommunicates;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
import util.FileUtil;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by vv on 22.04.2017.
 */
public class FileUploadController extends BasicAbstractController {


    public Result upload() {
        Http.MultipartFormData<File> body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> picture = body.getFile("picture");
        if (picture != null) {
            String fileName = picture.getFilename();
            String contentType = picture.getContentType();
            File file = picture.getFile();
            File fileToSave = new File(getPlaceToObserve() + "/" + picture.getFilename());
            try{
                Files.copy(file,fileToSave);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe){
                Logger.error("Unable to write file");
            }
            Logger.error("File Handled Cuccessfully");
            return redirect(GO_HOME);
        } else {
            flash("error", "Missing file");
            return badRequest();
        }
    }

    public Result delete(String fileName){
        List<File> files = FileUtil.getCurrentFileNames();
        File fileToDelete = null;
        for (File file : files) {
            if(file.getName().equals(fileName)){
                fileToDelete = file;
                break;
            }
        }
        boolean deletionResult = FileUtil.deleteGivenFile(fileToDelete);
        if(!deletionResult){
//            i am not able to add smthg here
            backendErrors.add(AppCommunicates.UNABLE_TO_DELETE_FILE);
        }
        return redirect(GO_HOME);
    }
}
```

I am not able to add nor access list from other controllers